# Linked list removing from head

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

In a linked list when there's only one Node situation  and I try to remove it using reoveFromHead(); I get a nullpointer at the toString() method.

```
public void removeFromHead(){
    if(head==null)
        return;

    else{
    head=head.next;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String result = " ";
    ListNode a=head;

    while (a.next!=null){
        result +=" "+a.item;
        a=a.next;
    }
    result+=" "+a.item;
    return result;
}
```

Can someone please point out where the mistake is?

Comment: When you remove the sole head, head = null. So a==head makes a = null. You will get nullpointer at a.next

Answer (score 5):

if `head=head.next;` gives you `null` (because there is no more items) then you cant call `a.next` because `a` is `null`.

```
public String toString() {
    String result = " ";
    ListNode a=head;
    if(a!=null){
        while (a.next!=null){
            result +=" "+a.item;
            a=a.next;
        }
    result+=" "+a.item;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you initialize the `next` parameter to a `null` value, when you remove your last node, `head` will now point to `null`.

When you do this: `a = head`, you are assigning `a` to null since there are no more nodes left. When you try and access the `.next` property, `a` will be null so you get that exception.

To fix this:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = " ";
    ListNode a=head;

    if(a != null)
    {
        while (a.next!=null){
            result +=" "+a.item;
            a=a.next;
        }
        result+=" "+a.item;
    }

    else 
    {
         result = "List is Empty";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are checking only for the condition where head is `null` and if head is not null, you are making the head to point to its next.

When there is only one node in the list, that is the head, so when you are making it to point to next, and there is no next to point to, you get a null pointer exception.